# Remove excess comma in a string in Java

Tags: java

I have an SQL string defined as follows:

```
String query = "SELECT NAME,, AGE,, Dep, as, Department, FROM, Employee, WHERE =, :param1";
```

I want to make the query as: `SELECT NAME, AGE, Dep as Department FROM Employee WHERE = :param1`

Can someone please help with this in Java?

I have tried the `query.repaceAll(",,", "");` but it does not seem to work properly.

Comment: How did those comma get in there in the first place? I'd try to avoid that at the source instead of fragile post-processing later. Breaking SQL that way is scary.

Comment: We get the query from a file.

Comment: Define "but it does not seem to work properly.".  What happens?  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Where do you get that file? Cannot someone fix the file instead? Accepting unvetted (and in this case broken) SQL from a file and running it sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to fix the code that *adds* those additional commas.

Anyway, `query.replaceAll(",+", ",")` will squash any sequence of commas into one. Then you are stuck with the commas around the `as` keywords. Those you can replace by `.replaceAll(",\\s*[Aa][Ss]\\s*,", " as ")`. Similarly for the other keywords like `WHERE`, `FROM`, ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should try to fix the source of that query.

Here is an easy trick avoiding the use of regex:

```
 String query = "SELECT NAME,, AGE,, Dep, as, Department, FROM, Employee, WHERE =, :param1";
        query = query.replace(",,", "#").replace(",", "").replace("#", ",");
        System.out.println(query);
```

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, Dep as Department FROM Employee WHERE = :param1
```

Comment: If you want to use a regex: `query = query.replaceAll(",(?=\\s)", "");`. It uses a positive lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the query was generated from a list that was then joined by ", ".
Therefore, all you need to do is

```
query = query.replaceAll(", ", "");
```

I will mention again as others have already done that *this is a terrible idea* with all kinds of security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
String newQuery = Stream.of(query.split(",,"))
        .map(s -> s.replace(",", ""))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```